# Nginx server_name is set to mydomain.com, so why is www.mydomain.com getting served too?

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, amazon-route53

I have my Nginx conf set up as follows:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    ...
}
```

When I load `https://mydomain.com`, the site loads fine.
But when I load `https://www.mydomain.com`, the site loads as well. Why is this happening?

I set up the DNS records using Amazon Route 53 as:

```
A        mydomain.com        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (IP)
CNAME    www.mydomain.com    mydomain.com
```

So is a request to `www.mydomain.com` arriving at Nginx as a request to `mydomain.com`?

If so, how do I differentiate requests to `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` at my server?

Comment: Unless you're using newfangled SNI, that's how it works. The hostname is part of the encrypted payload - name-based virtualhosts don't work with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only `server` block that listens to port 443, it is used for all SSL connections to the server, independent of the actual domain name.

You need to make a `server` block with `listen 443 ssl default_server` entry to make a virtual host that is served when no other `server` block matches.